# Connections between level curves of multivariate quantiles and probability of occurrence

Tags: confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis, quantiles

I've been looking through the literature of multivariate quantiles (e.g. Chaudhuri 1996, Hallin et al. 2010). The definitions all seem reasonable and I can see how they extend the notion of a univariate quantile, but from the perspective of someone trying to use these quantiles to understand data, these seem to be much harder to understand intuitively than a univariate quantile. If you give me the 0.05 and 0.95 quantile, then I can say, "Okay, 90% of my data is going to fall between these points." Are there any results that would say something like "If you construct the curve of multivariate quantiles corresponding to vectors of norm X, then as you receive more observations this converges to a curve such that there is Y probability that an observation will fall inside this curve?